# Generic Type Compatibility what am I doing wrong

Tags: c#, generics

Given below code, when I create a dictionary `Dictionary<System.Type, ICrud<IShape>>`  I can not add to the dictionary like so. It does not compile `Add(typeof(FourSideShape), new dataservice_FourSideShape<FourSideShape>())`

What am I doing wrong?

```
 public interface ICrud<in T> where T: IShape
    {
        void save(T form);
    }
public class dataservice_Shape<T>  where T : IShape
{
    public void save(T form) {

    }
}


public class dataservice_FourSideShape<T> : ICrud<T> where T : FourSideShape 
{
    public void save(T form)
    {

    }
}

public interface IShape {
    string ShapeName {get;}
}

public abstract class Shape : IShape
{
    public abstract string ShapeName { get; }
}

public class FourSideShape : Shape
{
    public override string ShapeName
    {
        get
        {
            return "FourSided";
        }
    }
}

   Dictionary<System.Type, ICrud<IShape>> services = new Dictionary<System.Type, ICrud<IShape>>();

   // fill the map
   this.services.Add(typeof(FourSideShape), new dataservice_FourSideShape());
```

Comment: The type `dataservice_FourSideShape<FourSideShape>` is not castable to `ICrud<IShape>`. It is castable to `ICrud<FourSideShape>`, but just because `FourSideShape` is an `IShape` that doesn't mean that `ICrud<FourSideShape>` is castable to `ICrud<IShape>`.

Comment: `T` on `ICrud` must be co-variant (change `in` to `out`) in order for `someA<someB>` to be castable to `ISomeA<ISomeB>`, However, this means you cannot have a method taking `T` as a parameter, only returning `T`

Comment: @Rob This should be an answer, which is more easier for others having similar questions to find.

Comment: @DannyChen I'll post it as a wiki-answer, as I feel that it's not fleshed-out enough (don't have much time to go in depth), and doesn't really provide a *solution* to OP's question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` on `ICrud` must be co-variant (change `in` to `out`), in order for `someA<someB>` to be castable to `ISomeA<ISomeB>`

However, this means you cannot have a method taking `T` as a parameter, only returning `T` - (your save method is invalid).

Here's an example of *why* you can't do what you're trying to do:

```
void Main()
{
    var c = new Crud<Shape>(); //Crud contains a List<Shape>
    c.Save(new Shape());       //Crud.SavedItems is a List<Shape> with one item

    ICrud<IShape> broken = ((ICrud<IShape>)c);
    broken.Save(new AnotherShape()); // Invalid ! 
                                     // Trying to add a 'AnotherShape' to a List<Shape>
}

public interface IShape {
    string ShapeName {get;}
}

public interface ICrud<in T> where T: IShape
{
   void save(T form);
}

public class Shape : IShape {
    public string ShapeName { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherShape : IShape {
    public string ShapeName { get; set; }
}

public class Crud<T> : ICrud<T> where T : IShape
{
    public List<T> SavedItems  = new List<T>();
    public void save(T form)
    {
        //Do some saving..
        SavedItems.Add(form);
    }
}
```

You'll have to re-architect your code. Perhaps change `void save(T form);` to `void save(IShape form);` and remove the templating?

Comment: Doesn't completely solve the issue because I need a the save method